# photoshop color border black

Tags: image, photoshop

here is my image:

[image]

You can't see it but there is a white border surrounding this image. What I want is to remove the white border and make it either disappear or turn black.

I'm fairly new to design and photoshop so please let me know if theres anything you need.

Comment: Maybe ask [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Nothing to do with programming, but click the `Image` menu, then `Trim` and you are all done.

Answer (score 1):

ditto, wrong place but either:

- image / trim, select options 1 or 2
- image / canvas, reduce height and width by border dimensions and apply to centre
- select marque tool, select / all, then hold 'alt' and draw marque around area to keep. Fill remaining area (edge) with background colour